# facebook error: an active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The first time I login with facebook SDK, it works without any error. But when I tried log out and login again, facebook error appears. The error is `"Facebook error: an active access token must be used to query information about the current user"` and the `getAccessToken()` returns as null.  Any answer and comment will be appreciated.

**Login Activity.java**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (APP_ID == null) {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Application ID must be specified before running");
    }
    try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.ff.fbin", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("TAG", "Reverse FB key: "+Base64Coder.encodeLines(md.digest()));
       }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }



    mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);
    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
    mLoginButton.init(this, mFacebook, mPermissions);
 }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    boolean isLogined = mFacebook.isSessionValid();
    Log.i(TAG, "getAccessToken, onActivity:" +mFacebook.getAccessToken());

    if (isLogined){
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new SampleRequestListener());
    }
}

public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response2: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);

            //Retrieve user information from facebook

final Runnable mUpdateResultsSuccess = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateResultsInUiSuccess();
    }
};

private void updateResultsInUiSuccess() {
        if (loginSuccess){
            Log.i(TAG, "Login FB done");
            finish();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
            helper.insert_user(mFacebook.getAccessToken());
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent2);

        } else {
            loading_text.setText("Error Processing");
            Log.i(TAG, "Login FB failed");
            try {
                mFacebook.logout(this);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: "+e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            SessionStore.clear(this);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Login Failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}


public class SampleAuthListener implements com.ff.fbin.SessionEvents.AuthListener {

    @Override
    public void onAuthSucceed() {
        Log.i(TAG, "You have logged in! ");

        boolean isLogined = mFacebook.isSessionValid();
        Log.i(TAG, "isLogined: "+isLogined);

        if(!isFinishing()){

        };

        if (isLogined){
            mAsyncRunner.request("me", new SampleRequestListener());
            pDialog.setMessage("Login in process......");
            pDialog.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Login Failed: " + error);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public class SampleLogoutListener implements com.ff.fbin.SessionEvents.LogoutListener {
    @Override
    public void onLogoutBegin() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logging out...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutFinish() {
        Log.i(TAG, "You have logged out! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. I wasn't getting it a few days ago and haven't changed anything since.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you post out a question regarding that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question solved, apparently the issue came from these sessionEvents. `SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());`

I removed the above code and move SessionStore.restore into onResume and it worked without error. The above code keep on create new SampleAuthListener() and causing it to stack together and do the same thing multiple times. That's the reason cause facebook error for my project.